# ASP.NET select * from table and save them in variable

Tags: asp.net, select

I'am new in asp.net. I want to select values from database table.
If it was PHP I would do it like following code.

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = ".$d." ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   $firstname = $row['firstname'];
   $lastname = $row['lastname'];

 }
```

How would I do if it was in asp.net if I use SqlConnection ...and SqlCommand   or maybe if there is some beter Connections.... 
 Thank you in advance guys....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Create a command, using a parameter
var command = new SqlCommand("select firstname, lastname from table where id=@id");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//use a using statement to ensure the connection gets disposed properly
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
    command.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();
    //execute the command and load the results in a data table
    dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
}

//loop through the results of the data table
foreach(var row in dt.Rows)
{
    var firstname = row.Field<string>("firstname");
    var lastname = row.Field<string>("lastname");
    //do something with firstname and lastname
}
```

This isn't a direct translation since I'm storing the values in a `DataTable`, but that is usually better than leaving the data connection open.

Comment: thank you for your qiuck response. I did as you wrote but it gives me an error as following : Foreach statment cannot operate on variables of type ’system.Data.Data.Table’ becouse ’system.Data.Data.Table’ does not contain a public definition for ’GetEnumeration’  I don't know what to do. I'am using alraedy using System.Data.Common;  and using System.Data;. Thank you again